# What is the right way for using git and composer for modules in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, deploy

Each of my module has a repository. I have dependency for my modules in composer.json in project folder.
For deployment I need:

- in production: `git clone`, `composer install`.
- in develop: `git clone`, `composer install` and prepare my modules to develop.

After `composer install` magento create folders for my modules in */vendor* and in */app/code/*. Also developers recommend to use */app/code/* for developing instead */vendor*.

But how I can add **git tracking** for modules?
What do with a modules if need to execute `composer install`?

Comment: You can read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90503/33057

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for myself.

Project modules will be without git in *app/code/Vendor/*.

Common modules use git and composer in *vendor/*.